# Am I using C# delegates in a useful way?

Tags: c#, delegates

I am doing a simple exercise using delegates in C#. The basic premise is that it simply performs calculations like addition and subtraction.

```
public class Calculator
{
    public static int Add(int num1, int num2)
    {
        return num1 + num2;
    }

    public static int Multiply(int num1, int num2)
    {
        return num1 * num2; 
    }

    public static int Subtract(int num1, int num2)
    {
        return num1 - num2;
    }
}
```

And I have created a delegate that will call these functions in another class.

```
public delegate int CalculatorDelegate(int num1, int num2);
```

The implementation class looks like this:

```
public class Calculation
{
    public int PerformCalculation(int choice, int number1, int number2)
    {
        CalculatorDelegate cd;
        if (choice == 1)
        {
            cd = Calculator.Add;
            return cd(number1, number2);
        }
        else if (choice == 2)
        {
            cd = Calculator.Subtract;
            return cd(number1, number2);
        }
        else if (choice == 3)
        {
            cd = Calculator.Multiply;
            return cd(number1, number2);
        }
        else
        {
            cd = Calculator.Add;
            return cd(number1, number2);
        }
    }

}
```

What's confusing me about delegates is why not just do the following instead?

```
if (choice == 1)
{
    return Calculator.Add(number1,number2);
}
```

I think my confusion is surrounding the fact that if these methods are already static, what's the point of even making a delegate to them. I can simply just call them as static methods. If I try to make the methods non-static, then I cant have my delegate point to them in this other class, without creating some object of the other class.

I am all turned around on this example and what it even accomplishes and maybe someone can provide me some insight as to if I'm even using this remotely close to how it should be?

Comment: Delegates are for late-bound function calls. Say you have a type, say a `Worker` that does a task. The worker might be defined with a delegate as one of its member variables and it might use that delegate, not knowing what the actual task to be performed is, until it is bound and invoked. In the example shown above, a delegate is rather useless, but it is showing you how delegates work (you have a variable `cd` and you bind it to several different methods depending on the branch of execution, then execute it)

Comment: A better example is with ASP.NET, delegates are extensively used. If you've ever used ASP.NET, it uses Controller Actions to handle HTTP requests. ASP.NET does not know what actual logic you want to happen with HTTP requests, but it will take your controller and invoke its methods as delegates in order to abstract away much of the HTTP-specific code so that you can focus on building your application without worrying about the granular details of HTTP transmissions.

Comment: @user1538301 I'm not too sure ASP.NET is a good example because callers of delegates don't know the name of the method, if they did they wouldn't use a delegate.  Since the behind-the-scenes script _knows_ the name of the controller action, ASP.NET simply performs a one-off lookup of the concrete method to invoke before caching it.  This is more likely an example of _"late binding"_ and .NET Reflection than delegates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delegates are types. Types that take a reference to a function, rather then some other value.

Delegates are there to hand functions as a argument to another function. Or to be used as the type for a generic class - mostly collections in practice. There are one of the *many* replacements for naked pointers that had to be invented, so .NET could shield you from having to handle naked pointers.

However they are also a case where the repalcement turned out to be *better* by a fair margin. For example, it is very possible to replace a switch/case with a `Dictionary<caseLabel, delegateThatTakesAArgument>`. If I gave you a `int` pointer in Native C++. you could not tell if this was a single variable I hand in by reference, the start of a array or a Function that returns int. With all those Pointer replacements, you know.

For this specific case, those functions themself are overkill. Delegates are even more overkill. That "PerformCalculation" function, sounds like it should be the User Input Interpreation part of a Console Application, not a function.

However there are not a lot of good, *unambigious* examples for Delegate use. So for learning it propably works okay. It is often a case where you have to make a judgement call between a switch/case with hardcoded operation and Delegates.

However Events are one of the rare clear cut case for Delegates I can think off. If you learn them for nothing else, learn them for Events.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a Repl demonstrating a Worker pattern utilizing basic delegates (`Action`s, a type of delegate built into the standard library that takes no parameters and returns nothing).

You can check it out [here](https://repl.it/@piboistudios/Delegates).

ETA: The most common use-case for delegates is asynchronous/threaded programming.

Threads require delegates to run as they do not know the code to be run beforehand, they simply carry it as a parameter into the newly created thread of execution, it would otherwise be impossible to create threads (well, without having lower-level access than C# provides)

Check out the MSDN docs on the [Threading API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread?view=netframework-4.8)

Similarly, in asynchronous programming, you will generally need a callback (which would be a delegate in C#) in order to defer execution of the code until pre-existing conditions are met. (A runloop for example, a common alternative to threading which uses a single thread to execute multiple tasks "concurrently" step-by-step)

Answer (score 0):

Once way you could use `delegate`s in your example is to have a mapping from choice to `CalculatorDelegate`, then you just lookup the desired calculation and perform it:

```
static List<CalculatorDelegate> ChoiceMap = new List<CalculatorDelegate> { Calculator.Add, Calculator.Subtract, Calculator.Multiply };

public class Calculation {
    public int PerformCalculation(int choice, int number1, int number2) =>
        ChoiceMap[choice-1](number1, number2);
}
```

But since delegates are converted automatically from lambdas (`CalculatorDelegate` is essentially `Func<int,int,int>`), you no longer need the `Calculator` class:

```
static List<CalculatorDelegate> ChoiceMap = new List<CalculatorDelegate> {
    (n1, n2) => n1+n2,
    (n1, n2) => n1-n2,
    (n1, n2) => n1*n2
};
```

Note that the types of `n1` and `n2` in each lambda are inferred from `CalculatorDelegate`. Now adding new operations to `PerformCalculation` is simply a matter of adding a new lambda to the `ChoiceMap`.

Hopefully you can see how you could use a more complicated type for `ChoiceMap`, such as a `Dictionary<string,Func<int,int,int>>` where each key is a string representing an operator (e.g. `"+"`) and the value is the operation to perform, which makes mapping to a simple calculator easy.

I use a similar `Dictionary` in a command line switch management helper, where each entry has the command name, the number of arguments, the delegate (method) to call (which may be a lambda when simple enough), the command grouping and some help text, where help output is generated automatically from the same `Dictionary`.